# What is the easiest way to build a FrameworkElement that has bold and italic markup text?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, bold, italic

**Is there any more elegant way to do the following?**

Basically I need an easy way to **programatically** build a `WrapPanel` (or other FrameworkElement) that:

- **wraps** correctly
- allows some words to have **bold** text
- allows some words to have **italic** text
- allows other **formatting**, e.g. color, background
- ideal would be some method that converts e.g. "`This is <b>bold</b> and this is <i>italic</i> text.`" into an appropriate FrameworkElement so I can e.g. **add it to a StackPanel** and display it.

Code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestAddTextBlock2343
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            WrapPanel wp = new WrapPanel();

            wp.AddTextBlock("This is a sentence with ");

            {
                TextBlock tb = wp.AddTextBlockAndReturn("bold text");
                tb.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            }

            wp.AddTextBlock(" and ");

            {
                TextBlock tb = wp.AddTextBlockAndReturn("italic text");
                tb.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
            }

            wp.AddTextBlock(" in it.");
        }
    }

    public static class XamlHelpers
    {
        public static TextBlock AddTextBlockAndReturn(this WrapPanel wp, string text)
        {
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = text;
            wp.Children.Add(tb);
            return tb;
        }

        public static void AddTextBlock(this WrapPanel wp, string text)
        {
            TextBlock tb = wp.AddTextBlockAndReturn(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: I discovered in a different answer that the `TextBlock` also has an `Inlines` collection to which one can add `Run`s. [Anvaka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290812/wpf-display-formatted-multiline-text-using-data-binding/2290905#2290905) ingeniously uses an attached property as a sort of converter.

---

What I think will suit your situation is a `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` and a `FlowDocument`. I describe manual creation of one through an `IValueConverter` a little bit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156541/how-to-insert-copyright-trademark-service-mark-etc-into-wpf-textbox-when-font/2159536#2159536).

You'll likely use similar helper functions as you've shown in your example, but the `FlowDocument` is already much like HTML and will handle wrapping effortlessly.

You add `Paragraph`s to the `FlowDocument`, you add `Run`s to the `Paragraph`, and each `Run` derives from `TextElement` so it has a lot of the same properties that `TextBlock`s do.

```
FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
Paragraph par = new Paragraph();
doc.Blocks.Add( par );

Run r;
r = new Run( "This is " );
par.Inlines.Add( r );

r = new Run( "bold" );
r.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
par.Inlines.Add( r );

r = new Run( " and this is " );
par.Inlines.Add( r );

r = new Run( "italic" );
r.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
par.Inlines.Add( r );

r = new Run( " text." );
par.Inlines.Add( r );
```

---

Also, if the formatting substrings are going to remain restricted to bold/italic tags or some other extremely simple markup, use of `Regex.Split()` might be the easiest way to determine the separate `Run`s from a single string. It allows you to split a string into multiple strings but keep your "delimiters".