# WPF Display formatted multiline text using data binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, text, multiline, formatted

I need to display the following using WPF databinding (the values change). Headers must be bold, the info lines are normal text. If info for a given header does not exist, I want to collapse that section, including the header. I prefer all the data (header and info items) be in one formatted string that can line break where I want.

**Header1:**

My info 1

My info 2

**Header2:**

My info 3

My info 4

Answer (score 4):

One more approach to try. Use [TextBlock.Inlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines.aspx). Then bind your model to the TextBlock, and either in custom [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) or via custom attached property parse your model to populate TextBlock's inlines.

Here is an example of Attached property that takes Text string and makes every second word bold:

```
public class RunExtender : DependencyObject
{
    public static string GetText(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(TextProperty);
    }

    public static void SetText(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Text", typeof(string), typeof(RunExtender), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnBindingTextChanged));

    private static void OnBindingTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bindingText = e.NewValue as string;
        var text = d as TextBlock;
        if (text != null)
        {
            text.Inlines.Clear();
            var words = bindingText.Split(' ');
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                var word = words[i];
                var inline = new Run() {Text = word + ' '};
                if (i%2 == 0)
                {
                    inline.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                }
                text.Inlines.Add(inline);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is not a production quality code, and it's taken from Silverlight demo, but you get the idea.

Hope this helps.

Cheers, Anvaka.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the bolding in a style I think your best bet would be to break your string up and use `TextBlocks` within a `StackPanel` within an `Expander`.

Alternatively you could do it in a `RichTextBox` with your whole string, but I think your string would have to contain the `<bold></bold>` tags.